# Having issue with jQuery hover function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, click, hover

## JS

```
$(".row").live("hover",
    function()
    {
        $(".remove").fadeIn();
    }
    );
$(".row").live("blur",
    function()
    {
        $(".remove").fadeOut();
    }
    );
```

## HTML Markup

```
<div class="row chapter" node="1">
  <img class="remove" src="design/images/remove.png">
  Sample
</div>
<div class="row chapter" node="2">
  <img class="remove" src="design/images/remove.png">
  Sample 2
</div>
```

What I want to do is,

1. to fade in on hover event, image with class `.remove` (which stands
   **inside hovered `.row` div**) and fade out on blur event.
2. On `.remove` click, get parent div's node attribute

## JsFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/3VG5P/3/

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. To fade in on hover event, image with class .remove (which stands inside hovered .row div) and fade out on blur event.

This will toggle the class "remove" within the hovered row.

```
$('.row').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.remove').stop(true, true).fadeIn();
}, function(){
  $(this).find('.remove').stop(true, true).fadeOut();
});
```

You should also use [stop(true, true)](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) to clear the animation queue and end any ongoing animation.

> 1. On .remove click, get parent div's node attribute

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    var nodeValue = $parent.attr('node') || "missing-node-value";
    console.log("node =", nodeValue); // DEBUG
    $parent.slideUp();
});
```

View **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/TkcsH/)**.

Comment: Updated my answer with the `click` event for `.remove` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Check the syntax:

```
(".remove").fadeIn();
//Should be
$(".remove").fadeIn();

Try:
$(this).children(".remove").fadeIn();
```

**Edited:**
BLUR events dont work on DIVs so you could try using mouseout, like

```
$(".row").live("mouseout", function() {
   $(this).children(".remove").fadeOut();
});
```

Comment: But it fades in all .remove at once. I need the one which stands inside hovered div

Comment: blur events dont work on div's so try using mouseout, see the edited code pls

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".row").hover(function(){
   $(".remove", this).stop().fadeIn();
}, function(){
  $(".remove", this).stop().fadeOut();
});
```

try this one.

Answer (score 1):

This is a job for CSS, not jQuery. I would use this simple CSS:

```
.row .remove {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
    transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
}
.row:hover .remove {
    opacity: 1;
}​
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/KPQ5h/

If you still want javascript:

```
$(".row").on({
    mouseover: function() {
        $(this).find('.remove').fadeIn();
    },
    mouseout: function() {
        $(this).find('.remove').fadeOut();
    }
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KPQ5h/1/

Comment: Very good solution for 1st problem. UP. Now 2nd: On .remove click, get parent div's node attribute. How can I do this?